# Laravel mass assignment not saving fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, mass-assignment

I have 2 tables within one function that I'd like to save data to. One is the `Users` table, and the second one is a `Clinic` table.

My user's table is currently working correctly, but I'm unsure if it's 'best practice':

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => Str::title($request->get('name')),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
])

    ->clinic()->create($request->only([
        'name' => Str::title('clinic_name'),
        'telephone',
        'address_1',
        'address_2',
        'city',
        'postcode'
    ]));
```

My problem occurs at the 'name' column of the `Clinic` table. It just doesn't save it, even though it's in the $fillable array in my `Clinic` column:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'telephone'', 'address_1',
                       'address_2', 'city', 'postcode'];
```

I have attempted to 'Chain' the methods together, as I want to save the 'user_id' within the `Clinic` table because they're related.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the `name` key in your `$request->only()` call:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name' => Str::title($request->get('name')),
    'email' => $request->get('email'),
    'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
])->clinic()->create($request->only([
    'name' => Str::title('clinic_name'), // This is overriding your 'name' field.
    'telephone',
    'address_1',
    'address_2',
    'city',
    'postcode'
]));
```

If you want to run `Str::title()` over the requests `clinic_name`, you'll need to assign the attributes manually like so:

```
$user = User::create([
    'name'     => Str::title($request->get('name')),
    'email'    => $request->get('email'),
    'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
])->clinic()->create([
    'name'      => Str::title($request->get('clinic_name')),
    'telephone' => $request->get('telephone'),
    'address_1' => $request->get('address_1'),
    'address_2' => $request->get('address_2'),
    'city'      => $request->get('city'),
    'postcode'  => $request->get('postcode'),
]);
```

**Note**: Just as a tip, you can also just retrieve request input as a property like so:

```
->create([
    'name' => $request->name // Performs $request->get('name').
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `'name' => Str::title('clinic_name')` when using `create()`, it must be a single key as `'name'`.

You can use the following before creating the user:

```
$request->replace('name' => Str::title('clinic_name'));
```